How to remove some ssh keys to be used when connecting to server
ssh -vv -D 1618 -C -N someserver

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:xxx agent
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: prayogo.x@xxx.com RSA SHA256:180K+xxx agent
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: x.prayogo@xxxy.com ED25519 SHA256:xxxy agent
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: x-production-eb-key-pair RSA SHA256:xxxy+1ZNflh/xxxy agent
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: prayogo.x@xxxz.com RSA SHA256:/yG/xxxz+2eWo agent
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: x.prayogo@xxxv.lu  ED25519 SHA256:xxxv agent
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Received disconnect from 10.240.0.1 port 22:2: Too many authentication failures

I already deleted some keys above from ~/.ssh/* but it still getting attempted, how is this possible?

If you deleted some of the keys shown in the output, please update the question with the new debug output you get after deleting the keys, and show the result of ls /home/ubuntu/.ssh

What is the output of ssh-add -l?

@Bodo that's the output after i delete the key

@KamilMaciorowski ssh-add -l shows that it still there, even physical files is no longer in .ssh/*

You can still use the keys because there is an SSH agent running. Apparently several private key identities have been added to it. Added identities are kept in memory. An identity added from a regular file (i.e. from a private key on disk) does not require the file to be available later; you can even "borrow" a key from another system (example). The act of deleting some keys from the filesystem did not affect your SSH agent, it had already loaded the identities.
The word agent at the end of a line like this one:

debug1: Offering public key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:xxx agent


indicates that this attempt to authenticate you involves the agent, not the file. …/.ssh/id_rsa here only indicates the file that was used when adding the identity; the file may still exist or it may no longer exist, this is irrelevant.
Programs like ssh can communicate with the agent via a socket. They can learn the path to the socket by inspecting the environment variable named SSH_AUTH_SOCK. Your ssh inherited the environment from your shell. If you run echo "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" in the shell then you will see the path to the socket.
Run ssh-add -l or ssh-add -L to see the identities currently represented by the agent.
You can remove an identity from the agent with ssh-add -d /path/to/key, but this requires a path to the (private or public) key file specifying the identity you want to remove. If you no longer have any file specifying the identity you want to remove, consider removing all identities with ssh-add -D, then re-adding all identities you didn't want to remove. You (re-)add a key by running ssh-agent /path/to/key.
See man 1 ssh-add for details.
Running ssh with empty or unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK will make it unable to communicate with the agent:
# empty
SSH_AUTH_SOCK= ssh …

# unset
env -u SSH_AUTH_SOCK ssh …

This is useful when you want to ignore the agent on demand, without changing the state of the agent and without losing your ability to use the agent in the future.

A gpg-agent also includes optional SSH agent functionality, and can persist the SSH keys from one login session to another with its own encrypted key storage mechanism. If you are familiar with the common OpenSSH agent, this may be somewhat surprising behavior.
